# How to install and use a gem inside an rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, refinerycms, activeadmin

I use refinery-cms to create a webshop in ruby-on-rails and refinery is largely based on engines. I have therefore made a "webshop" engine with all my models, and i want to install the gem "activeadmin" inside this engine, so when i run "rails g active_admin:install" it will create the model and config files inside my engine dir. I can only get it to install in the root app

Hope you can help me

/Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was just to cd in to the engine folder, and run the generator command from there.